# Reporting Services .. How to Export an Excel Spreadsheet with Hyperlinks disabled

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, export-to-excel

I'm using the ReportViewer control to display a Report within a WebForm, i've also implemented the "Export to Excel" feature, by calling the Render method of the Server Report

eg

```
ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.Render("Excel",etc,etc,etc);
```

My problem is that the exported report contains Hyperlinks that link to other reports, I wish these to appear in the webform but not appear hence be disabled in the Exported Spreadsheet (generated by the Code above).

Does anyone have a way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, we ended up passing an extra report parameter in, and having the report remove the links, and then calling the render as normal.

Simple but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A report has no advance knowledge of what form it is going to take when exported. If you need different layouts depending on what format the report exports to, then you need to make separate reports for each of those layouts.

Comment: Thanks, my current plan is to pass a bool parameter and switch the links off in the report.